# Added a table to a dbml, but it doesn't show up in code

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql

I am using VS2010 with C#, and linq-to-sql.

Does anyone have any ideas of where to start looking for a solution?

My database has a 'Cats' table and there is a 'Feet' and 'EyeColour' table that are both linked to it with a one-to-one relationship. The 'Feet' table works fine with linq-to-sql, but 'EyeColour' does not.

I dragged the EyeColour table from the database explorer. It has a one-to-one relationship with another item (Cats) in the database. All properties match 'Feet'.

doing Cat.Feet works, but doing Cat.EyeColour does not, it doesn't appear in the intellisense and gives me a cannot find it error, but both tables are there and the links/relationships are identical.

I tried deleting the designer.cs file so it regenerated, but still nothing. Tried closing/opening VS as well.

Any clues as to what might cause this?

Comment: Did you make any change in SQL Field after you dragged and dropped table to dbml?

Comment: What do you mean by SQL Field? I dragged and dropped the tables in, and then added a one-to-one relationship between EyeColour and Cat. The properties (and relationship) are all identical to Feet, which works. The only property I had to change was on the relationship, from one-to-many to one-to-one. I also tried renaming the table from EyeColour to EyeColourz to see if it would refresh somehow, but still nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved, turns out there was no primary key on the EyeColour - it was just set to not null unique (which is pretty much the same, but I guess Visual Studio didn't like that).